# Excel If cell A matches cell A on another sheet, then add text to cell B on sheet 1

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple Sheets with almost the same content and I'm trying to find a code to copy cells `Sheet2!D` to `Sheet1!D` only if `Sheet2!A = Sheet1!A` and copy cells `Sheet3!D` to `Sheet1!D` only if `Sheet3!A = Sheet1!A`

For example

**Sheet 1 - Original**

```
Nr         A          B           C        D
1         500         red        500 
2         220         yellow     200
3         130         blue       120
4         560         purple     210
5         862         cyan       190
```

**Sheet 2 - Original**

```
Nr          A           B           C        D
12         500         red        500       perch
18         220         yellow     200       apple
15         130         blue       120       
16         560         purple     210
23         862         cyan       190       strowberry
```

**Sheet 3 - Original**

```
Nr          A           B           C        D
47         500         red        500       
55         220         yellow     200       
65         130         blue       120       apricot
74         560         purple     210       blueberry 
44         862         cyan       190
```

**Sheet 1 - after**

```
Nr          A           B           C        D
1          500         red        500       perch
2          220         yellow     200       apple
3          130         blue       120       apricot
4          560         purple     210       blueberry
5          862         cyan       190       strowberry
```

Could somebody sugest me how to do this job? I was searched here and I couldn't find anything. Thank you in advice

//Later edit - "Nr"= row number
I`m sorry for missunderstanding in previous post

Answer (score 0):

In your Original sheet, you can put this in `D1` and drag down

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$D$1:$D$4,MATCH($B1&$C1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$4&Sheet2!$C$1:$C$4,0)),"")
```

It's a [multiple criteria index/match](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/).

Comment: Is not working because row 1 from Sheet1 is not the same with row 1 from Sheet2

Comment: @IULIANTELIANU - Can you just adjust the ranges to fit where your data is? Can you please clarify that in your original post via an edit?

Comment: sorry for missunderstanding. I`ve eddited the original post with full info. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use below formula in Sheet1 Range D1

```
=Index(Sheet2!D:D,Match(Sheet1!B1,Sheet2!B:B,0))
```

Comment: Is not working because **row 1 from Sheet1** _is not the same with_ **row 1 from Sheet2**